# Faucet connected incorrectly, hot to cold , cold to hot. No water comes out

Tags: kitchen-sink

I hooked up new kitchen faucet incorrectly, hot to cold, cold to hot. It worked fine for 2 months.

Today i had low water pressure and within a hour no water, hot or cold.  I switched my hot to hot, cold to cold. Still no water at all now, .

I'm guessing  something apparently went bad from not hooking up the right way, hot to hot cold to cold?

Do I need a another new faucet or can I replace something in this faucet?.

Comment: It is unlikely that  having the connections backwards would damage the faucet.  We need to know the make and model or at least what type of faucet it is. Have you done any investigations to see if there is any problems with other fixtures in the building. Have you disconnected the supply line and then opened the valve just a little to see if there is water coming from the main line?

Comment: You've probably done this - but unscrew the aerator on the faucet and make sure the screens are cleared of debris. In addition to normal mineral buildup I've seen instances where a rubber washer in the shutoff valve has disintegrated completely blocking water flow. Since you've recently swapped the feeds that may not be your problem but something is blocking flow - start there.

Comment: Thank you for replying!! Checked the aerator it's fine, and there is water going to the faucet. Hot and cold lines are fine. Tuscany 1 handle with Sprayer from Menards. I just purchased another and I will take apart this one I'm removing to see how a faucet works. It probably has something blocking the flow as suggested but I am scared to take apart and then reinstall only to have a leaky faucet for sure then.  So thank you Alaskaman and Honeydo......Lisa

Comment: most one handle faucets reverse the hot and cold if you spin the cartridge 180 degrees

Comment: Why did you have low water pressure? Were they doing work outside? If so, I'd suspect something has gunked up your valve.